# How can the tags julian and julian-date be merged? How to re-tag errors?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Looking at the descriptions of the tags [julian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julian) and [julian-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julian-date), the descriptions are essentially the same. Looking at questions that bear these dates, many are about the ordinal date (defined in ISO 8601 as "date representing a particular calendar day by its calendar year and its ordinal number within its calendar year" but the phrase is used outside ISO 8601 too).

So how can we merge [julian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julian) (64 posts) and [julian-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julian-date) (45 posts)?

What should we do about the questions that are mis-tagged. Should there be a new category ordinal-date?

Comment: Which one to keep? Julian-date? There are 64 in Julian, 45 in Julian-date

Comment: I think it would be better to keep julian-date. If it is convenient to capitalize it and eliminate the dash, that would be better, since the entry of the glossary of the _Explanatory Supplement to the Astronomical Almanac_ 3rd ed. is "Julian date". Just "julian" could be mixed up with Julian calendar, which does not have (and probably does not need) a tag.

Comment: Except that tags are always lower-case (no exceptions allowed) that seems the best cause of action

Comment: Suggest "julian" as a synonym over here, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/julian-date/synonyms And then convince/wait for people to vote. I have waited a year since my synonym-request meta post and gotten one other vote so far :)

Comment: @Frank the problem is that very few people have enough score on rare tags like that.

Comment: @o11c: on other SE sites, basically only moderators can create tag synonyms, because *nobody* has enough reputation to vote on, let alone suggest, tag synonyms.

Comment: @Martha `s/reputation/score/`

Comment: Frank's recommended course of action, making a suggestion at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/julian-date/synonyms) does not see to be available to me since I have less that 2500 reputation points.

Comment: @GerardAshton: I have the reputation, but not the score in the tag... and according to the [top users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/julian-date/topusers) list, only 4 users have the necessary score at the moment.

Comment: Ha, well, I guess we're all out of luck. Small tags are effectively immune to merges/synonymization, it seems. The tag I was modifying ([tag:subset]) probably has a hundred users who could vote to synonymize, but that wasn't enough either. I wonder if there is a meta thread complaining about this issue.